# How to copy SQL Server backup file from one network to another network with credential?

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy the backup file with certain criteria

1. copy backup from one network to another network with that server credential
2. copy the latest backup. Example:(on the source folder it will keep last 3 days backup only).

   `@echo off`

   `net use y: /d /y`

   `net use y: \\{127.0.0.1}\{folder} {password} /user:{domain}\{user name}`

   `robocopy "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup" Y:\{destination location} /e /purge /z`

   But it doesn't work. it is not copied

Comment: What did you try till now?  Please post minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @tukan i will update what i tried

Comment: where does it fail? What error message is displayed?